# When is the closure removed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am curious how the closure in Javascript removed.

I know the definition of closure. It is a variable which is referred by child function inside of a parent function that lifecycle is over.

Here is the example below:

```
    let inner;

    function outerFunction() {
      let outerValue = 'Mike'

      function innerFunction() {
        let message = `${outerValue} is a developer`

        console.log(message) // Mike is a developer
      }

      inner = innerFunction;

      return
    }

    outerFunction()
    inner()
```

As you can see, when **outerFunction** is called, eventually it is removed from callstack due to return statement.

After **outerFunction**, **inside** which is the variable assigned **innerFunction** is called.

**innerFunction** shows the message 'Mike is a developer'. However it does not return.

In this case, when does **innerFunction** is removed from callstack?

The function does not return and hold a variable from **outerFunction**. If this remains in memory then it must be a huge waste.

Or is **innerFunction** also removed when **outerFunction** returns?

Comment: "However it does not return." it does. It implicitly returns `undefined`.  Try logging `console.log(inner())`. BTW you can omit `return` statement in your `outerFunction` as well.

Comment: "*In this case, when does innerFunction is removed from callstack?*" when it finishes executing. Like any other function. "*If this remains in memory then it must be a huge waste.*" the callstack and the general memory are two different concepts. At any rate, there is nothing magical about closures - they just hold reference to some data. If `inner` has no references to it, it can be GC'd along with the data `inner` holds a reference to. As long as `inner` has references, it's will not be GC'd. Again, same as any other object.